# Finding palindrome String throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException, possible cause?

Tags: java, string

Provided a String, my objective is to check if I can make that String a palindrome string even after re-arranging the characters.

For eg: `aaabbbb` can be made palindrome by changing to : `bbaaabb`

So what I did try is to compare all the permutations of the string with its reverse, if it exists, print a YES! . And here is the code so far:

```
private static void permutation(String prefix, String str)
{
    temp.setLength(0); //temp is a StringBuilder
    int n = str.length();
    if((n==0) && (str.charAt(0)==str.charAt(n-1)))
    {
        temp.append(prefix);
        temp.reverse();
        if(prefix.equals(temp.toString()))
        {
            System.out.println("YES");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            permutation(prefix+str.charAt(i),str.substring(0,i)+str.substring(i+1,n));
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, at runtime I get a **java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException** at this line: `permutation(prefix+str.charAt(i),str.substring(0,i)+str.substring(i+1,n));`

What might be possibly causing this?

Comment: What steps have you taken to debug the problem yourself?

Comment: This is because when i = n-1, then substring(i+1, n) will become substring(n, n)... since string is 0 indexed.. it will through out of bounds exception.

Comment: You are trying to access an index which does not exist...also, you can try - count the letters in the given string...for even case every letter should have a count of `2` and for odd cases - same holds true except for one letter in the given string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line will give you the exception too:

```
if((n==0) && (str.charAt(0)==str.charAt(n-1)))
```

If n==0 then the string is empty, and charAt(0) will fail. Not sure what you're testing here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to debug this for you, but I will suggest a process for how to debug this kind of thing yourself.

1. **Identify the problem**. All of the detail about the palindromes is irrelevant. The problem is a `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` when calling one of the methods on the String.
2. **Narrow in on exactly what's failing**. There are several method calls in the line that is failing. If it's not obvious which method call is the problem, either single-step through it with a debugger or break that line into several lines, e.g. by creating intermediate variables to hold intermediate state.
3. **Reproduce the problem in a simplified example**. Create a new class with a `main()` method or write a unit test and write code that shows the problem. Remove everything that isn't absolutely essential to show the problem.
4. **Fix your example.** Once you've isolated the problem and **read the documentation**, it will probably be obvious how to fix it. If it's not, and you're still stuck, post the simple example on Stack Overflow and explain what you are expecting and what you're getting.
5. **Fix your code.** Apply the same fix to your original code.

Comment: While I really like your answer, I can't upvote it, because it does not directly answer the question (or so my gut feels). Maybe you could make a selfanswered question from it?

Answer (score 0):

`String index out of bound exception` -This exception is thrown by the methods of the String class, in order to indicate that an index is either negative, or greater than the size of the string itself.

In above code you are calling `permutation()` method recursively .

Let's say we passed `String str="xy"` and prefix as `""` to `permutation()` method first time.

As its length is more than 0 it will come to the `else` block.
In else block we are looping `str` with its length.

Here length i.e  `n is 2`.
In first loop, `i=0`. So `prefix + str.charAt(i)` will give `"" + "x" = "x"` and `str.substring(0,i)+str.substring(i+1,n)` 
will give `str.substring(0,0)+str.substring(0+1,2)=""+"y"="y"`.

Now again we are passing these values to `permutation()` method; i.e. `permutation("x","y")`.
So the time when you passed these value in method, at that time  instantly string `str` became `"y"` and string prefix became `"x"`
but still you are in loop, and in second loop `i=1` and `prefix+str.charAt(1)` i.e. `"x"+"y".charAt(1)` will throw exception.

Here you can see string `str="y"`, length is 1 and we are trying to get char at position 1.  This is why you got this exception.